# changing proxy python script

Tags: python, proxy

I'm looking to change the proxy that my python script runs from. Would this be possible by say changing the HTTP_PROXY at the beginning and end of my python script like the following?

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/"
```

I'm doing this because there is a bug in phantomjs/selenium that stops me from being able to put in proxy authentication.

alternatively, is there another way I can set the proxy that my python script runs through at the beginning and end of the script?

Answer (score 2):

That should be possible, using the requests package:

```
import requests
http_proxy  = "http://10.10.1.10:3128/"
https_proxy = "https://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/"
ftp_proxy   = "http://10.10.1.10:3128/"
proxyDict = { "http"  : http_proxy, 
          "https" : https_proxy, 
          "ftp"   : ftp_proxy}
```

Then to request info through the proxy:

```
page = requests.get('https://www.google.com.au/', proxies=proxyDict)
```